# MVC APIController With CustomNames

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, routes

So im new to `netcoreapp` and im trying to convert my old rest api to the new one.

The problem is that im having trouble to use custom methods name and parameters.

I only want to have `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]` and then the action and the parameter.

So for example

```
[HttpGet]
public List<string> GetStrings(string firstString, string lastString){
 // my code here
}
```

and then i try calling this, which is not working at all

```
baseUrl/controller/GetStrings?firstString=test&lastString=test2
```

See my controller below to understand my problem

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class YoutubeController : ControllerBase, IYoutubeController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<YoutubeVideoInfo> GetVideoAsync(string videoId)
    {
        // my code
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<YoutubeItem> Playlist([FromQuery]string playlistId)
    {
        // My code
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public YoutubeVideoCollection Search(string searchString, int pageSize = 50, string relatedTo = null, VideoSearchType videoSearchType = VideoSearchType.Videos)
    {
     // my code
    }
}
```

}

I tried Calling Search like this, without any luck

```
https://localhost:44330/Youtube.Manager.Core.API/api/Youtube/Search?searchString=Eminem&pageSize=20&relatedTo=&videoSearchType=Videos
```

And this is my routing config

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
        });
```

Is there any other configration i need to have, and also please i do not want to  have too specify anything in my `[HttpGet]` Attribute.

In net framework i hade `WebApiConfig` which it could handle those kind of operation.
Is there nothing like it in `netcoreapp`?

Comment: Remove [ApiController] and the Route part, from there you can add the Route attribute to your methods

Comment: Yes, but this is exacly what i do not want. When i have an controller action and parameter, then mvc should know what to do since there is no conflict right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the action name to be part of the route, you need to update the `[Route(..)]` attribute to take the action into account. You're already using the `[controller]` token in your example, so just add `[action]`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) for a detailed explanation of token replacement.

Comment: Yepp that was it, its working now. Just one quastion, if i remove `route attr` should it not take the settings that was specified in the startup class eg `app.UseMvc(routes =>` and make it a global settings ? why dose it not work?

Comment: `MapRoute` sets up [conventional routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#conventional-routing), but [`[ApiController]` requires attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing-requirement).

Answer (score 1):

Decorate your controller like this:

```
[ApiController]
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
public class YoutubeController : ControllerBase, IYoutubeController
{
    [HttpPost, Route("GetVideoAsync")]
    public async Task<YoutubeVideoInfo> GetVideoAsync(string videoId)
    {
        // my code
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("Playlist")]
    public List<YoutubeItem> Playlist([FromQuery]string playlistId)
    {
        // My code
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("Search/{searchString}/{pageSize}/{relatedTo}/{videoSearchType}")]
    public YoutubeVideoCollection Search(string searchString, int pageSize = 50, string relatedTo = null, VideoSearchType videoSearchType = VideoSearchType.Videos)
    {
     // my code
    }
}
```

And add the following line in your RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Comment: app.UseMvc(routes=>  ` routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` dose not exist. i do not have any other configration. where should i put this. And i would really like to skip using Route attribute like the good old days when using `WebApiConfig` is there no way ?

Comment: But you are using the Route attribute over the controller `[Route("api/[controller]")]`. I don't get the part to skip this attribute. Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, but im only using it once. I do not want to put route in every method. im i will still use it until there is a better global solution. Like WebApiConfig which after will remove all routing